# If $0$ is a partial limit of $a_{n}$ (for some subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$), so does $\infty$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n} a_{n+1}=1$,

Is the following statement true or false:
If $0$ is a partial limit of $a_{n}$ (for some subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$), so does $\infty$.

I think it's true, for example: $a_{n}=\lbrace \frac{1}{n},  odd| n, even\rbrace$
But haven't found an elegant way to prove it.

Comment: If $|a_{n_k}|\to 0$, then since $|a_{n_k+1}|$ becomes arbitrarily close to $1/|a_{n_k}|$, which is arbitrarily large, the result follows.

Comment: It's trivial 

If $a_{n_k}$ converges to $0$ then 

let $b_{n_k}=a_{n_k+1}$

The sequence $\{b_{n_k}\}$ is unbounded hence we can find a subsequence which converges to infinity or minus infinity.

Comment: I always get confused with the $n_{k}$ index. Let me try and put it in my own words so I could better grasp it: exists such a subsequence $a_{n_{k}}\to 0$, so because of the given limit, which applies for any $n>N$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n_{k}}a_{n_{k}+1}=1$ when $n_{k}>N$ and as @uniquesolution arithmetics gives the result. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily $\infty.$ $-\infty$ is also possible (but not both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of limit we have:

For all $m >0$:

i) $\exists N_1>0, \forall n \ge N_1: |a_na_{n+1}-1| < \frac{1}{m} \implies 1-\frac{1}{m} < a_na_{n+1}$

ii) $\exists N_2>0, \forall n_k \ge N_2: |a_{n_k}| < \frac{1}{m}$

Let $N = max(N_1,N_2), \forall n_k \ge N:$

$$ 1-\frac{1}{m} < a_{n_k}a_{n_k+1}$$
$$ 1-\frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{m}|a_{n_k+1}|$$
$$m-1 <  |a_{n_k+1}|$$

Letting $m \uparrow \infty: |a_{n_k+1}| \rightarrow \infty$

Then you should consider the sequence $a_{n_k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For every $M\in \mathbb N$ there exist infinitely many $n\in \mathbb N$ for which $|a_n|<1/M.$  So for every $M\in \mathbb N$ there exist infinitely many $n$ for which $|a_{n+1}|>M.$  So there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty}|a_{n_k}|= \infty.$

If there is such  a sub-sequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ where the set $S=\{k:a_{n_k}>0\}$ is infinite, then  there exists a sub-sub-sequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in S}$ that goes to $\infty;$ If not, then $(a_{n_k})_k$ goes to $-\infty.$

We can explicitly construct such a sub-sequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ as follows: Let $m_1$ be the least $n$ such that $|a_n|<1,$ and let $n_1=1+m_1$. Recursively, let $m_{k+1}$ be the least $n$ such that $n>m_k$ and $|a_n|<1/(k+1),$ and let $n_{k+1}=1+m_{k+1}.$

In the above paragraph we can replace both occurrences of the words "the least" with the word "any". Using "the least" gives a particular sub-sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There exists $N$ such that $a_na_{n+1} > 0$ for $n\ge N.$ Suppose $a_N > 0.$ Then a simple argument shows $a_n> 0$ for $n\ge N.$ Assume now some subsequence $a_{n_k} \to 0.$ Then for large $k$ we know two things happen: $a_{n_k}>0,$ and $a_{n_k}a_{n_k+1}> 1/2.$ For these $k$ we have $a_{n_k+1}> 1/(2a_{n_k}) \to +\infty.$ Hence $a_{n_k+1} \to +\infty$ as desired.

The other possibility is that $a_N<0$ above. We would then have $a_n < 0$ for $n\ge N,$ and we would find the analogous subsequence $a_{n_k+1},$ this time $\to -\infty.$

Note that in this problem only one of the possibilities $\pm \infty$ is possible for an infinite subsequential limit.